# How can we add tax and shipping charge in braintree paypal checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am working with braintree paypal checkout, it is working fine for me, but i am not able to add tax and shipping charge, i tried to get some information, but that is also not working for me, here is my current code for braintree checkout

```
var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
var client_token = "<?php echo \Braintree\ClientToken::generate(); ?>";
 // Render the PayPal button

    paypal.Button.render({

        // Pass in the Braintree SDK

        braintree: braintree,

        // Pass in your Braintree authorization key

        client: {
            sandbox: client_token,
            production: '<insert production auth key>'
        },

        // Set your environment

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

        payment: function(data, actions) {

            // Make a call to create the payment

            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { 
                                total: <?php echo $cart_total_amount; ?>, 
                                currency: 'USD'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Call your server with data.nonce to finalize the payment

            console.log('Braintree nonce:', data.nonce);

            // Get the payment and buyer details

            return actions.payment.get().then(function(payment) {
                $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
                console.log('Payment details:', payment);
                var payment_id = payment.id;
                var total_amount = '<?php echo $cart_total_amount; ?>';
                $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url : '<?php $_SERVER["DOCUMET_ROOT"] ?>/media/secure_checkout/create_order_braintree.php',
                            data : 'payment_id='+payment_id+'&total_amount='+total_amount,
                            dataType : 'json',
                            success: function(msg) {
                                $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                                if(msg.status == '1') {
                                    //$("#myModal").modal('show');
                                    document.location.href= 'http://<?php  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/media/secure_checkout/checkout.php?payment=confirm';
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(msg) {
                                $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
                            }
                });
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Can anyone please tell me what i need to do to add tax and shipping charge in it?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support@braintreepayments.com.</sub>

Braintree doesn't have parameters for `tax` or `shipping`. You'll need to create this logic on your side and pass the total into the `amount` parameter.

Comment: But in case of Recurring/Subscription, how can i manage tax? The rate of tax is different in different province or country. Then this is not good practice to create different plan according to buyer's place.

Comment: Erica, can you confirm or correct the information in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293864/1000655)?  Thanks!

Comment: @harishsharma This question isn't about Recurring/Subscription, but [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293864/1000655) may have some helpful information for you.  You can override the plan amount (or perhaps create a "tax" addon, and override that amount).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're following the code at [Integrate PayPal Checkout Using the Braintree SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/).  Check out the available options for the `actions.payment.create()` call [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#2-set-up-a-payment).  Note that `tax` and `shipping` are there.  More details on the [Payments API page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create).  Note: You still need to calculate the total so it includes tax and shipping, like Erica said.

If you want to create the payments server-side, it seems you can pass [`taxAmount`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#tax_amount) and [`shippingAmount`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#shipping_amount) to Braintree's [`transaction::sale()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php) method.  It's also possible to pass these at a line-item level.  Again, you need to calculate the total so it includes tax and shipping.  It seems you'll have to include some other fields as well, since `taxAmount` is a [Level 2](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/level-2-and-3-processing/required-fields/php#level-2-data) field, and `shippingAmount` is a [Level 3](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/level-2-and-3-processing/required-fields/php#level-3-data) field.  I haven't used it, so I can't say how it works, or how well it works.  I imagine (hope) these fields get passed onto PayPal, if PayPal is used as payment method.

For recurring transactions: I don't see any tax/shipping-specific fields, but you can override the `price` to include tax when you create the subscription (at least with the server-side Braintree API).  Alternatively, I think if you create an add-on for tax, you could override that at subscription-create time without knowing the subscription price.  Either way, I'm not sure if you can easily update the subscription as tax rates change (as laws change).