# Add Shipping charge in Paypal checkout using Braintree SDK

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree-sandbox

I am implement the Braintree SDK for payment in my E-Commerce application(iOS and Android).but I am not able to and shipping charge in “BTPayPalRequest”.

How to add Shipping charge in this SDK?

My Code is below:

```
    braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: “Key”)!

    let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient: braintreeClient)
    payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self


    payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self // Optional
    // Specify the transaction amount here. "2.32" is used in this example.
    let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: strAmmount)

    /// Cart Item
    var items = [BTPayPalLineItem]()
    for Dict in ArrMyCartDetails{
        let item = BTPayPalLineItem(quantity: String(Q), unitAmount: String(SP), name: strProductName, kind: .debit)
        items.append(item)
    }
    request.lineItems = items
    request.intent = .sale
    request.displayName = AppTitle

    request.isShippingAddressRequired = false
    request.isShippingAddressEditable = false

    request.shippingAddressOverride = BTPostalAddress.init()
    request.currencyCode = "AUD"

    payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(request) { (tokenizedPayPalAccount, error) in
        if let tokenizedPayPalAccount = tokenizedPayPalAccount {
            print("Got a nonce: \(tokenizedPayPalAccount.nonce)")

        } else if error != nil {
            // Handle error here...
            self.ShowMessage(strMsg: "something wrong in payment process.")

        } else {
            // Buyer canceled payment approval
            self.ShowMessage(strMsg: "you cancel payment!")

        }
    }
```

Comment: According to answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46489672/4056108) SDK doesn't have parameter for shipping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we add tax and shipping charge in braintree paypal checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489672/how-can-we-add-tax-and-shipping-charge-in-braintree-paypal-checkout)